# Solr9 query field alias returns no documents

Tags: solr, solrcloud

We're currently in the process of migrating our solr search cluster from `7.7` to `9.1` and have noticed the following issue:
Take a simple query we have to demonstrate this issue
`select?fl=code:id,id:ext_id&indent=true&q.op=OR&q=*:*&rows=2` queried in solr 7
will return the following results

```
 {
  "responseHeader":{
    "zkConnected":true,
    "status":0,
    "QTime":90,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "indent":"true",
      "fl":"code:id, ext_id",
      "q.op":"OR",
      "rows":"2",
      "useParams":"",
      "_":"1677082343247"}},
  "response":{"numFound":43663026,"start":0,"maxScore":1.0,"numFoundExact":true,"docs":[
      {
        "id":4566629,
        "code":"HTS79YFC1DBVQ8SQVNZF6SZV8R"},
      {
        "id":11308031,
        "code":"YERR5FZB8DBPQ4KTRX0HYMCHP8"}]
  }}
```

However, running the same query in solr9 returns the following:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "zkConnected":true,
    "status":0,
    "QTime":79,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "indent":"true",
      "fl":"code:id,id:ext_id",
      "q.op":"OR",
      "rows":"2",
      "useParams":"",
      "_":"1677082343247"}},
  "response":{"numFound":43663026,"start":0,"maxScore":1.0,"numFoundExact":true,"docs":[]
  }}
```

Note, the `docs` array is empty. I've tried this with the edismax and dismax query parsers and it's still the same. I can find no errors in the logs to show something went wrong and nothing in the changelogs to say that this changed. The issue appears to be caused by the `displayField` of `id` being mapped when that field already exists in the index
The schema definition for the `id` field has not changed

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" required="true" />
```

Is this a bug in Solr9, or what has changed to cause this?

Comment: I'm using Solr 9.1.1 and a similar query is working fine. Did you use Solr web app UI for these queries? If you upgraded Solr in-place, maybe some frontend code remained cached, try ctrl+f5 to refresh web UI.

Comment: Yeah, tried in on Solr 9.1.1 via postman. Still the same.